# How can I stream my screen to other computers?

Tags: vnc, remote, tightvncserver

I am looking for something like the TightVnc Projector but cross-platform and free if possible.

I have seen stuff like iTALC but it was hard to setup on Windows and long-winded for what I need. all I need to do is pass a command on start-up to create a server for my desktop's screen (running 12.10 LTS). I have a laptop running 13.10 to use as a client.

I would also like a viewer on my Windows and Ubuntu clients to start-up in their respective ways. (I am aware of the procedure of this.)
 Thanks in advance

Comment: My Ubuntu Desktop-slash-server setup is 12.10 LTS and my laptop is 13.10.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the new information about your server and clients you put in the comments.

Comment: Have you looked at Desktop Sharing and/or Remina remote desktop client?

Comment: Hey, post that as an answer :-p

Comment: jackmawer, Did it work for you? To notify someone use write his name as @ubfan1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Desktop Sharing and/or the Remina Remote Desktop Client. Those were working for me under 12.04.

In late Ubuntu releases (like 14.04), Desktop Sharing was removed from System Settings, but you can still find and use it, and it's provided by the 'Vino' package, installed with `sudo apt-get install vino`. To setup the package run the `vino-preferences` command.

Comment: Is it cross-platform?

Comment: @hakermania, Yeah, it's a VNC.

Answer (score 0):

Xpra (https://xpra.org/) is great cross-platform alternative.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).